# Go to hyperlink within excel workbook

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

What excel formula can I use to launch a hyperlink, go to the worksheet the hyper link takes you to and extract specific information into a table? e.g worksheet 1 has a directory list with specific codes - if my cell equals to one of those codes, can my table populate with specific information)

Answer (score 0):

You might need to show sample data for people to understand your goal. Maybe you only need an IF formula, like `=IF(A1="Code A", SheetA!C15, IF(A1="Code B", SheetB!C15, IF(A1="Code C", SheetC!C15, "")))`.